# Selenium utility to wait for an Element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new to the selenium framework and writing a method for the presence of element. Below is the method which I wrote:

```
public class WebUtlities {
    WebDriver driver;

    public void waitforanelement(WebElement element)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By) element));
    }
```

When I call this method for an element, I see the below error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6 cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.By
    at Uilities.WebUtlities.waitforanelement(WebUtlities.java:16)
    at TestScripts.Testcases.Selfpay(Testcases.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Please correct me how to make it work for the element to wait

Comment: what is the 'By' you have added.. the error is on that only.

Comment: You are casting `WebElement` object to `BY` which is wrong. you should try `By.ByClassName`, `By.ByCssSelector`, `By.ById` etc..follow this link for better understanding ..https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html

Comment: You really shouldn't do this. Do you really want to wait 20 secs for every element search? In general, you should wait for the page to finish loading and then you should be good to find any element on the page (no waiting). The exception to this is when you perform an action and the page changes content. In those cases, wait for the content to change and then you're good again.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
public class WebUtlities {
    WebDriver driver;

    public void waitforanelement(WebElement element)
    {
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath of that element"))); //you can use any other By like id, cssselector, name, linktext etc
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
public void waitforanelement(By element)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(element));
}
```

when  u call the method, do like below:

```
By css = By.cssSelector("ur selector");

waitforanelement(css);
```

hope this will help u.

Comment: Tried the above but when I call this method for the WebElement, I am seeing the below error **The method waitforanelement(By) in the type WebUtlities is not applicable for the arguments (WebElement)**

Comment: your method presenceOfElementLocated take by locator as parameter, so if u pass a webelement inside presenceOfElementLocated() method, it will definitely show an error. To see the api details see here: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with this line:

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By) element));`

Firstly, the `presenceOfElementLocated` method is used to locate an element on the page, rather than to check that a previously found element is present on the page - as such you should change the argument for your `waitforanelement` method to accept a `By` locator instead of a `WebElement` like so:

`public void waitforanelement(By by)`

You should then subsequently change the arguments passed to the `presenceOfElementLocated` method like so:

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by));`

[The Javadoc for the `By` class lists the locators you can use.](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem as you can see from the error is that

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By) element));
```

returns an WebElement instance which should be assigned to an WebElement. So It can not cast  a WebElement to nothing.

Follow the following list for complete list of methods of ExpectedConditions Class.
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html

Try the following,

```
public WebElement waitforanelement(WebElement element)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
         WebElement Element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By) element));
   return Element1;
    }
```